# nested function calls using with statements for authentication

Tags: python, tableau-api

I have a couple of functions that I'm trying to write for tableau (not that that should matter necessarily).  The important bit is that it's hierarchical so projects contain workbooks which contain views.  project/workbook/view So I have a function for each `get_project`, `get_workbook`, and `get_view`.  In order to get view, I first have to get a workbook and before I get a workbook I first have to get a project.

```py
def get_view():
    # need to get the workbook before I get the view
    workbook = get_workbook() #can't have this in the with statement or the connection closes
    with sign_in():
        # do some stuff

# and get workbook looks like 
def get_workbook():
    # need to get the project before I can the workbook
    project = get_project()
    with sign_in():
        # do some stuff
```

tableau signs out after the `with` statement. But I'm wondering if there's a better way to have these statements so that I can keep the same connection open instead of opening and closing?  [This github comment](https://github.com/tableau/server-client-python/issues/693#issuecomment-695005306) is what got me worried about it.

Right now my only thought is to just pass a live_cxn flag but it's a lot of boilerplate.  I don't know if some decorator or something would make this more pythonic. It works, but I don't get any of the benefit of the with statements, mainly if anything errors out my connection is left open.

```py
def get_view(live_cxn=False):
    if not live_cxn:
        sign_in()
    workbook = get_workbook(live_cxn=True)
    # do some stuff
    if not live_cxn:
        sign_out()

# and get workbook looks like 
def get_workbook(live_cxn=False):
    if not live_cxn:
        sign_in()
    project= get_project(live_cxn=True)
    # do some stuff
    if not live_cxn:
        sign_out()
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with Tableau and I'm not super clear on what your code ultimately does... but couldn't you simply `with sign_in():` and then call your `get` functions inside that block?

Comment: The point of using `with` is to ensure a connection is closed after you finish using it. If you don't want to close a connection, consider creating a class that opens the connection in its `__init__` and closes it in its `__del__`. The other methods don't have to worry about the connection then, and can just use the open connection. However, it seems odd that `sign_in()` doesn't return some sort of connection object - apparently the connection is global to whatever module you're using?

Comment: @Grismar I thought that was odd as well, but it appears to match how it's shown [here](https://tableau.github.io/server-client-python/docs/sign-in-out). (Also be careful about trusting `__del__`, it's not guaranteed to ever be called.)

Comment: I agree, although that's not too much of an issue in this case - what's more worrying here is that if you have two instances, but the module only has a single global connection, deleting one object might close the connection for all. It seems like the module either expects a user to use shortlived connections (as the linked example shows), or to use a context manager at a very high level. Alternatively, you could add a context manager to your own class and avoid the `__del__` that way, since you can close on `__exit__`.

Comment: @CrazyChucky, no because the one will close the other.  The connection is global.  The sign in just returns an authentication contextmanager.

Comment: What do you mean "the one will close the other"? If the connection is global, just sign in once at the top of your code.

Comment: It's a package and if it stays open too long it will also auto close.

Comment: How long do you *need* it to be open?

Comment: since it's a package that people import, it varies.  But the reason I did it like this is because I have some jobs that run over 10 hours and do many requests.  The individual requests don't take that long so I thought to do it based on request.  But usually people run get_view, which then opens the get_workbook, which opens the get_project.  I'm actually getting the 401002 intermittent problem I linked. Maybe my real question is, is it possible to stop the __exit__ of a with? THat's probably dumb though.

Comment: @CrazyChucky After diving into it, it seems it's worse than that.  If any other app ANYWHERE in existance tries to use the same PAT.  It invalidates the sign in. 
 This can't be standard practice right?  https://github.com/tableau/server-client-python/issues/717#issuecomment-723303874

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up just making a decorator.  Not sure this is the best, but it's still better than the boilerplate I was adding.

```py
import inspect
from functools import wraps
def check_sign_in(func):
    """a decorator to sign in and out of tableau online
    THE DECORATED FUNCTION MUST HAVE A KWARG 'has_cxn'
    and the calling function must call it as a kwarg
    """
    sig = inspect.signature(func)
    default_kwargs = {
        kw: value.default for kw, value in sig.parameters.items() if value.default != inspect.Signature.empty
    }
    if "has_cxn" not in default_kwargs.keys():
        raise ValueError("The decorated function must have a kwarg 'has_cxn'")

    @wraps(func)
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        has_cxn = {**default_kwargs, **kwargs}.get("has_cxn", False)
        if has_cxn:
            r = func(*args, **kwargs)
        else:
            logger.debug("Creating a new connection to Tableau Online")
            with server.auth.sign_in(tableau_auth):
                r = func(*args, **kwargs)
        return r
    return wrapper
```